# Change the state of an object that is stored in a set

Tags: java, object, set

Is there any good advice how to deal with mutable objects that are stored in Sets?

Some objects may define their equality (and hashCode) based on their internal state. When such objects are stored in Sets, in- or outside the controlled code, a mutation of the state may lead to inconsistency in the Set.

Is there any "best-practice" to avoid or deal with that, aside don't do it?

Example code:

```
static class A {
   String s;
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      return s.equals(((A)o).s);
   }
   public int hashCode() { 
      return s.hashCode();
   }
   public String toString() {
      return s;
   }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  A a0 = new A();
  a0.s = "Hello";
  A a1 = new A();
  a1.s = "World";

  HashSet<A> set = new HashSet<A>();
  set.add(a0);
  set.add(a1);

  System.out.println(set);

  a0.s = "World";

  System.out.println(set);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point the development team got this problem a lot when working with collections of entities that only got their key before being stored to the database. Their hashcode/equals depended on that key...

The solution we came up with was something along these lines:

```
public static <P> void rearrange(Set<P> set) {
    HashSet<P> temp = new HashSet<P>();
    temp.addAll(set);
    set.clear();
    set.addAll(temp);
}
```

Another idea was a Set implementation decorating a HashSet, but we quickly decided this would cause more problems on the long run. For the most part the above method is executed by 'framework' code transparently to the developer, but I am still not particularly happy with this solution.

Comment: To move the problem to the set is ok for me :) But for the sets using these objects too?

Comment: This solution moves the problem to the sets using the objects. so, these sets must be aware of/deal with the maybe changed objects. Good for the object, bad for the set.

Answer (score 0):

**Set** interface doesn't provide any method for getting a value and there is a reason to do that. 
[Java Set API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

So it doesn't expect that you get a value, modify it and then add it again. In your code that's what you doing; you modified a value stored in Set.

So ideally you should avoid it but if you want to modify any object inside Set then do below steps:

1. Remove Object from Set
2. Add a new modified object

This way your **hashcode/equality** contract will be guaranteed.

Comment: i must confess; i never noticed that there is no getter method in Set :)

Comment: This is more or less the Don't Do It answer. The problem is more, when you are not able to track where and when your objects are stored.

Comment: Yeah; but there is a way at least to deal with it :) Delete the object from set and then add it again. Nice question btw (+1)